# How to calculate mutual friend using cypher query in Neo4j as per facebook representation?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am describing a small part of facebook that is mutual friend calculation in Neo4j with graphical representaion. I want to share it with all of you who are beginners and interested with graph database specially neo4j with my tiny knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example of Facebook Representation to Calculate Mutual Friend Between the Two:**

- Cypher Query To Represent Friends Database:

  ```
  CREATE (Keanu:Person {name:'Keanu Reeves', born:1964})
  CREATE (Carrie:Person {name:'Carrie-Anne Moss', born:1967})
  CREATE (Laurence:Person {name:'Laurence Fishburne', born:1961})
  CREATE (JoelS:Person {name:'Joel Silver', born:1952})
  CREATE (DemiM:Person {name:'Demi Moore', born:1962})
  CREATE (KevinB:Person {name:'Kevin Bacon', born:1958})
  CREATE (KieferS:Person {name:'Kiefer Sutherland', born:1966})
  CREATE (NoahW:Person {name:'Noah Wyle', born:1971})
  CREATE
     (Keanu)-[:FRIENDS_WITH ]->(Carrie),
     (Keanu)-[:FRIENDS_WITH ]->(Laurence),
     (Keanu)-[:FRIENDS_WITH ]->(JoelS),
     (Keanu)-[:FRIENDS_WITH ]->(DemiM),
     (KevinB)-[:FRIENDS_WITH ]->(KieferS),
     (KevinB)-[:FRIENDS_WITH ]->(NoahW),
     (KevinB)-[:FRIENDS_WITH ]->(DemiM),
     (KevinB)-[:FRIENDS_WITH ]->(JoelS);
  ```
- Equivalent Graph Representation:
  [image: Mutual Friend Representation]
- Cypher Query to Retrieve Mutual Friend's Name between KevinB and
  Keanu:

  ```
   MATCH (Keanu:`Person` {name: "Keanu Reeves"})-[r]->(mutualFriend)<-[r1]-(Kevin:`Person` {name: "Kevin Bacon"}) RETURN mutualFriend.name
  ```
- Cypher Query to Return what Number of Mutual Friend with whom one of
  Keanu:

  ```
   MATCH (Keanu:`Person` {name: "Keanu Reeves"})-[r]->(mutualFriend)<-[r1]-(unknown) RETURN COUNT (mutualFriend) as NumberOfMutualFriend,unknown.name
  ```